# Derived Constructor

Tags: java, constructor, derived

In the following code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class MyClass1
{
     MyClass1()
     {
         System.out.println("base class");
     }
     public void print()
     {
        System.out.println("base print");
     }
}

class ChildClass extends MyClass1
{
    public ChildClass()
    {
       System.out.println("child class");
    }
    public void print()
    {

      System.out.println("child print");
    }
}
```

Why is it that when I create an instance of type ChildClass the constructor of the base class is also executed??

Answer (score 5):

Because your child class extends the base class - it's an instance of the base class and has all of the same fields and variables, etc.  Thus the base class must also be instantiated.

For a concrete example, imagine your base class had the following in:

```
public class Base
{
    final private int id;

    public Base()
    {
        this(-1);
    } 

    public Base(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
}
```

A final variable is guaranteed to be instantiated when the class is constructed.  Your child class will have an `id` field (even if it cannot access it directly with child methods), and since this field is private you cannot possible instantiate it with the child constructor - so a base class constructor **must** be called.

Bear in mind that this isn't solely an issue with final variables, nor is it unique to any particular features you may use - since your child class **is** a base class, it needs to be properly instantiated as one.

Answer (score 2):

Because that's what's supposed to happen :-)

Your derived class uses the base class *as a foundation*. In OO speak it **is-a** base class. That base class also needs to initialise itself, and consequently its constructor must be called.

It's not obvious from your example, but it will make more sense if you give your base class some (protected) members. Initialise them in the base constructor, and consequently they will have the expected values when viewed from your derived class upon construction.

See below. The field `value` is visible in the child class. What would you expect as the initialised value ?

```
public class MyClass1
{
     protected int value;
     MyClass1()
     {
         System.out.println("base class");
         this.value = 42;
     }
}

class ChildClass extends MyClass1
{
    public ChildClass()
    {
       // what would you expect 'value' to be here ?
       System.out.println("child class " + value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because compiler by default add super() constructor  in the child class  constructor if it is not specified . Every Constructor Should have either this() in case of without inheritance or super() method when ever there is an inheritance . To illustrate it i have taken this example .

```
  public class Vehicle {
    protected int wheels;
    protected int lights;

    Vehicle(){
        System.out.println("Vehicle Class Constructor");
        this.wheels=4;
        this.lights=2;
    }
 }
```

Vehicle is the parent class

```
 class Car extends Vehicle {
  public Car(){
    #Compiler add the super() constructor by default
        System.out.println("Car class constructor");
    }
}
```

Car is the Child class

```
public class TestCar {
   public static void main(String args[]){
       Car c = new Car();
       System.out.println("Wheels" + c.wheels);
       System.out.println("Lights" + c.lights);
   }
}
```

In above code snippet  When i compile the TestCar.java file  during the Compile time  the compiler looks for the Car constructor and checks whether Car class has any parent as soon as it checks that Car class extends the parent class Vehicle  , it checks whether user had provided super() in  inheritance tree . if not it adds one .

Hope this helps !